# How to stop/break replication between 2 domain controllers that are in same domain?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, replication

So I was attempting to break replication between 2 domain controllers by editing objects in AD, since I cant just go to powershell and stop it with command, but it was unsuccessfully. I have to stop it from "inside" operating exclusively on AD objects or schema. Would appreciate some solutions if possible.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? this is probably a terrible idea.

Comment: There is no problem it is a experiment. We were given their virtual machines and we need to stop replication and then be able to fix replication back up.

Comment: please read the guidelines. If this is a learning project it's not appropriate for this site. 
https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic
Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment.

Comment: Rapidly create new objects with the same name on multiple DCs at different sites to generate many object conflicts. Under certain circumstances, AD may give up trying to resolve these conflicts, and would require administrative intervention.

Answer (score 2):

For testing/temporary purposes, repadmin may be used to disable replication.

`repadmin /options +DISABLE_INBOUND_REPL`
`repadmin /options +DISABLE_OUTBOUND_REPL`

---

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/turn-on-that-scary-dc/ba-p/258950

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have been told that we aren't suppose to do it that way, because it belongs as if I turned off the replication directly, but I have to "accidentally" by editing some content in AD achieve that the replication is lost.

Comment: Who told you that?

Comment: So this "experiment" is for my project and my supervisors told me what I can do and what I am not supposed to do. That's why the way you sent me is good but they said don't do it that way.

Comment: It may be possible to break replication by disrupting network comms between two sites and then create an object with the same SamAccountName on multiple DCs. Then restore the network connection. Normally this would result in an object conflict, but I  have seen it happen in production environments where the site connection is down for hours. Replication would be broken until the offending objects were identified in the NTDS log and removed.

Comment: @twconnell: conflict (CNF) objects or lingering objects are two typical causes of replication shutdown. Provisioning processes are common sources, usually due to not maintaining an affinity to a/the specific domain controller during an operation or a series of operations, combined with the type of activities performed.